# How can an object type be unknown at compile time?

Tags: c++, compile-time, dynamic-binding

I am currently learning about dynamic binding and virtual functions. This is from Accelerated C++, chapter 13:

> [...] We want to make that decision at run time. That is, we want the
>   system to run the right function based on the actual type of the
>   objects passed to the function, which is known only at run time.

I don't understand the very idea that the type of an object can be unknown at compile time. Isn't it obvious from the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all.  Consider this example:

```
struct A {
  virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct B : A {
  virtual void f() { std::cerr << "In B::f()\n"; }
};

struct C : A {
  virtual void f() { std::cerr << "In C::f()\n"; }
};

static void f(A &a)
{
  a.f(); // How do we know which function to call at compile time?
}

int main(int,char**)
{
  B b;
  C c;
  f(b);
  f(c);
}
```

When the global function `f` is compiled, there is no way to know which function it should call.  In fact, it will need to call different functions each time.  The first time it is called with `f(b)`, it will need to call `B::f()`, and the second time it is called with `f(c)` it will need to call `C::f()`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a concept of *pointers*, where the variable holds only a "handle" to an actual object. The type of the actual object is not known at compile-time, only at runtime. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Greeter {
public:
    virtual void greet() = 0;
};

class HelloWorld : public Greeter {
public:
    void greet() {std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";}
};

class GoodbyeWorld : public Greeter {
public:
    void greet() {std::cout << "Goodbye, world!\n";}
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Greeter> greeter(new HelloWorld);
    greeter->greet();    // prints "Hello, world!"
    greeter.reset(new GoodbyeWorld);
    greeter->greet();    // prints "Goodbye, world!"
}
```

See also: Vaughn Cato's answer, which uses *references* (which is another way to hold a handle to an object).

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a pointer to base class pointing to a derived object

```
Base *pBase = new Derived;

// During compilation time, compiler looks for the method CallMe() in base class
// if defined in class Base, compiler is happy, no error
// But when you run it, the method call gets dynamically mapped to Derived::CallMe()

// ** provided CallMe() is virtual method in Base and derived class overrides it.

pBase->CallMe(); // the actual object type is known only during run-time.
```

Comment: That is probably _way_ above the OP's level, given the question the OP's asked.

Comment: Nevertheless my example is way simpler than yours but still conveys it effectively :)